# How to run facebook app in android through WIFI

Tags: android, android-wifi

I've an facebook application in android. Its working fine if I use through mobile network.
But when i try to run it through *WIFI* means,it didn't get login even.
Do i need to give any permissions for *WIFI* or some thing else I missed out?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure wifi is working :) check other apps on wifi....

Comment: facebook might be blocked in your WiFI environment.

Comment: If an appln works on mobile networks means that should also works on WIFI?

Comment: Your application is working on actual device?

Comment: yeah.Its working fine through mobile internet

Comment: And one more doubt is that if an appln works on actual device,will that same appln runs on CDMA devices?

Comment: May be facebook blocked as @Rajnikant told